# what should i add to get testmethod in visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

[TestMethod] is not getting in intellisense it is showing in red colour.
  this is my controller

```
 [TestMethod]  
 public ActionResult Index()  
 {           
    return View();    
 }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't look like a test method... What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the namespace Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting
```

and add a reference to the assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testmethodattribute(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testmethodattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)